# Will mastercard cover 3rd year of warranty on iphone with apple care?

Tags: mastercard, extended-warranty

I'm buying a new iphone outright and have some questions about a clause in the mastercard warranty. I called mastercard and they didn't sound very confident in their answer so I wanted to ask here.

Here's the mastercard [extended warranty contract](https://www.capitalone.com/media/doc/credit-cards/benefits-guide-platinum-mc.pdf) statement that applies to this purchase:

> If you purchase a service contract or an optional extended warranty
>   of twelve (12) months or less on your item, ***Extended Warranty will
>   cover up to an additional twelve (12) months after both the original
>   manufacturer’s (or U.S. store brand) warranty and the purchased
>   service contract or extended warranty coverage period end.*** If your
>   service contract or extended warranty exceeds twelve (12) months, this
>   coverage does not apply.

The question is: If I buy the phone with apple care I will get 1 year warranty automatically from apple that comes with the phone, the 1 year extended warranty with the apple care, and then does mastercard cover the 3rd year? I think the answer is yes based on the clause above but i'm not 100% certain.

Any input would be most appreciated.

Comment: That's how I read it.

Comment: I'd say no. "If your service contract or extended warranty exceeds twelve (12) months, this coverage does not apply." These plans offer year-2 coverage, but not if you already have it.

Comment: Agree with JoeTaxpayer.  You've highlighted the wrong part in that quote.  The first clause clearly says the entire thing only applies if you purchase an extended warranty for 12 months or less.

Comment: But it says `if you purchase a service contract or optional extended warranty.... [it] will cover up to 12 months after both the original... warranty and the ... extended warranty period has ended` So that's 12 months *after* the 1st year with the original warranty, and 2nd year with the extended, no?

Comment: I'd read it the way @JoeTaxpayer does, even with the separate pieces.  The mastercard provision covers contracts of <= 12 months in total between standard and extended warranties.

Answer (score 1):

No. This will NOT give you a third year of coverage because you will have 2 years of existing coverage, assuming the Apple Care contract that comes with the phone does not run concurrently with the Manufacturer's warranty. You should be aware that Apple Care is a Service Contract, and not a warranty per se, and therefore it may run concurrently with the basic warranty. You should be sure to check those details as well. When in doubt, assume you will NOT be covered in the third year, and who knows, maybe you will be pleasantly surprised.